# but problem i have they want 20,35,45 is step 15 then 10

Tags: c#

I'm taken c# class and have to write a program. You burn 5 calories per minute when running on a treadmill. Write a program that uses a loop to display the number of calories burned after 20,35,45 minutes. I know I can use a while or for loop. But problem I have those you use step say of 5 or 10 but as you see 20,35,45 is step 15 then 10 how would I work that into while or for loop?

Comment: int minutes = 20;

        while(minutes <= 50)
                {
                Console.WriteLine(minutes * 5 + " calories after " + minutes + " minures");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                minutes += 15;
                }
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: There are several ways to go about doing this problem. The most straight-forward being that you could just start at 0 minutes, loop each minute one at a time to count the calories per minute, and then have a `switch` or a series of `if` statements to do something special if `minutes` is equal to one of your values.

Comment: That code is going to skip over 45 entirely. `35 + 15 = 50` Also, if you want us to critique your code, you should add it to the body of your question, not as a comment.

Comment: IMO you could re-word this to ask for help in understanding the problem and solutions to approach it with an example of what you've tried. This shouldn't be a place to go for easy homework answers.

Comment: You could store the required minutes in an array and loop over it by avoiding the step problematic completely: `var displayAtMinutes = new int[] { 20, 35, 45 };`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.
Create a for loop and step 5 and check if any matches the given minutes to display. But there are better ways.

I'd rather write something like:

```
// just make a variable and put the calories per minute in it.
// it's just more clear to read and if you need to use it multiple times, 
// it avoids to put the value multiple times in your code.
var caloriesBurnedPerMinute = 5;
// this specifies an array of integers, (it detects that the values are integers.
var minutesToDisplay = new[] { 20, 25, 45 };

// make a loop over each value in the array
foreach(var minutes in minutesToDisplay)
{
    // I'd rather don't put the calculations in the writeline, easier to debug.
    var caloriesBurned = minutes * caloriesBurnedPerMinute;

    // display the value.
    Console.WriteLine($"Calories burned after {minutes} is {caloriesBurned}");
}
```

This way you don't need to write bruteforce loops, which just waste time/energy.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this out by creating a console app and pasting the code in this method into it. It sets calories burned per minute to a constant value of 5. Then iterates through minutes on treadmill starting at 1 minute and ending at 45. After each minute 5 calories are burned and at the minutes specified in the switch statement, the number of calories burned are stored in a variable and displayed to the screen.

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int calsBurnedPerMinute = 5;

        // i represents minutes between 1 and 45
        for (var i = 1; i <= 45; i++)
        {
            var calsBurned = 0;

            switch (i)
            {
                case 20:
                    calsBurned = calsBurnedPerMinute * i;
                    Console.WriteLine("Calories Burned After 20 minutes: " + calsBurned);
                    break;

                case 35:
                    calsBurned = calsBurnedPerMinute * i;
                    Console.WriteLine("Calories Burned After 35 minutes: " + calsBurned);
                    break;

                case 45:
                    calsBurned = calsBurnedPerMinute * i;
                    Console.WriteLine("Calories Burned After 45 minutes: " + calsBurned);
                    break;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Output:

- Calories burned after 20 minutes: 100
- Calories burned after 35 minutes: 175
- Calories burned after 45 minutes: 225